# What does $\Psi^*$ mean in Schrodinger's formulation of Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, notation, complex-numbers

I am not a physics student. In one of my courses, some fundamental concepts of Quantum mechanics were needed, so I was going through them when I stumbled upon this.

It says

$$\text{probability} = \int_a^b\Psi^*\Psi\mathrm{d}x\quad\biggl(= \int_a^b\Psi^2\mathrm{d}x\text{ if }\Psi\text{ is a real function}\biggr)$$

Is the $\Psi^*$ in this expression the wave function's conjugate, or something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct. $\Psi^{*}$ denotes the [complex conjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate).

Comment: ok, so in general the wave function is given to us and from there we need to proceed or it has general form for various cases that we need to be aware of?

Comment: Usually you get the wave function at time t=0 and the evolution of the wave function is governed by the Schrodinger equation.