# what is phase angle of wave function $\phi \,$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, double-slit-experiment

this is wave function:
$$\Psi{(\vec r, t)}=\Psi_0 e^{i(\vec k \cdot \vec r-\omega t)}$$
$$\Psi{(\vec r, t)}=A e^{i(\phi + \vec k \cdot \vec r-\omega t)}$$.

1. what is phase angle $\phi$ of wave function?
2. is there any graph that shows what is phase angle of waves?
3. how measure phase angle of light (double slit experiment)?

Comment: if some one is interested can improve this question

Comment: I'm not sure if this is homework but it certainly sounds like it might be so I added the homework tag. If I'm wrong, feel free to remove it.

Comment: I'd guess this question is an extension of http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28934 so it isn't homework.

Comment: @Colin K
 that is not homework but if you thought that is it, don't worry because homework tag is just a kind of general tag and doesn't make any sense

Comment: @BadBoy: Actually it makes a lot of sense and has a very specific meaning, so I wouldn't call it general at all.

Comment: @Colin K as you wish but,
doesn't make any sanse

Comment: The homework tag means that the question is the OPs homework or a study question. We are not here do do people's homework for them, or to help them cheat on assignments, so the homework tag lets us know that we should only provide hints and advice, but not complete and direct answers. When the homework tag is applied, you will not get answers, but only help in understanding the problem so you can find your own answer.

Comment: @Colin K hey guy i really did not care what the hell is homework tag means 
so lets  **don't dwell on
it**

Comment: Woah, somebody is a little cranky today.

Comment: @Colin K Wait until you try to reach your thesis, then we will seen who is cranky :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your questions 1 and 2: this graph shows the real part of $\Psi{(\vec r, t)}=A e^{i(\vec k \cdot \vec r-\omega t)} $ in blue and the real part of $\Psi{(\vec r, t)}=A e^{i(\phi + \vec k \cdot \vec r-\omega t)} $ in purple. Obviously $\Psi$ is a function of two variables, so you can regard the graph either as keeping $\vec r$ constant and varying $t$ or keeping $t$ constant and varying $\vec r$.

[image: PhaseShift]

The quantity $\phi$ is just the phase difference between the two waves e.g. the distance between the peaks shown by the arrow on the diagram.

The absolute value of $\phi$ has no physical significance because you can measure $\phi$ from any reference point you want. However the difference in $\phi$ between two wavefunctions has a very important physical meaning because it determines how the waves will interfere.

To address your question 3: actually the mention of the double slit experiment is spot on. The slits split the incoming light (or electrons or whatever) into two sources, call these $\Psi_a$ and $\Psi_b$, and if you take some point on the screen, this point will receive light from $\Psi_a$ and from $\Psi_b$, but the phase of the two waves, $\phi_a$ and $\phi_b$ won't be the same.

There isn't any physical meaning to the absolute phase of $\Psi_a$ and $\Psi_b$, $\phi_a$ and $\phi_b$, but if $\phi_a - \phi_b$ is an even multiple of $\pi$ ($2\pi$, $4\pi$, etc) the waves will be in sync and you'll get constructive interference and a bright area. If the phase difference is an odd multiple of $\pi$ ($\pi$, $3\pi$ etc) the waves will interfere destructively and you get a dark spot. This is exactly why you get the pattern of alternating bright and dark bands in the two slit experiment - it's because the phase difference, $\phi_a - \phi_b$, varies as you move along the screen.

So no experiment can measure the absolute value of $\phi_a$ or $\phi_b$, because the absolute value has no physical significance. However the double slit experiment can measure the phase difference $\phi_a - \phi_b$.

Comment: phase angle $\phi$ has no physical significance 
wave Amplitude $A$ has no physical significance too!
is this really physics!?
i means it sucks me

do you have another graph for wave wave Amplitude (that i really don't know why its constant!)?

Comment: Remember it's the modulus of the wave function, $\Psi^*\Psi$, that has a physical significance. So it's true to say that the value of $A$ has no physical significance, but $A^2$ does! Also it's only the absolute value of the phase $\phi$ that has no significance. The phase difference, i.e. the differencve in $\phi$ for two or more waves, is exceedingly important and is the original of all interference phenomena.

Comment: ok what the hell, i just need to make sure that wave Amplitude is constant.
do you know why unit of the modulus of the wave function $|\Psi|^2=A^2$ is $m^{-3}$?

Comment: The modulus squared of the wave function gives the probability density i.e. the probability per unit volume. "Probability" is just a number and has no units, so the units of the modulus squared of the wave function are inverse volume.

Comment: do you really believe that  inverse of volume is constant!?

Comment: The *units* of $A$ are inverse volume. That doesn't make $\Psi$ constant. Although $A$ is constant because that's typically how it is defined -- as a (normalization) constant. Its constancy has nothing to do with its units.

Comment: The wavefuntion you are looking at, $A e^{i(\phi + \vec k \cdot \vec r-\omega t)}$ is an infinite plane wave. If you evaluate $\Psi^*\Psi$ for this wavefunction you'll find it is independant of $\vec r$ and $t$ i.e. it is constant everywhere. That's why the probability is constant everywhere. Different wavefunctions, e.g. the harmonic oscillator, give probabilities that are not constant everywhere.