# What does the * mean in spherical harmonics?

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

In Jackson's book about classical electrodynamics, this formula comes up:
$$q_{lm} = \int \mathrm d^3 x' \, Y^*_{lm}\left(\theta', \phi'\right) r'^l \rho\left(\vec x'\right)$$

What does that $^*$ mean?

Comment: what page? I have my copy right here

Comment: In my German one it is 170. It is equation (4.3).

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19259/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The superscript $*$ is a common notation for complex conjugate. Going back to check, (3.53) in the blue English edition states
$$Y_{l,m} = \sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{4\pi}\frac{(l-m)!}{(l+m)!}}P^m_l(\cos\theta)e^{im\phi}$$
which is followed by (3.54)
$$Y_{l,-m}(\theta,\phi) = (-1)^m Y^*_{l,m}(\theta,\phi),$$
making is clear that it has to be complex conjugation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have this sense of “clear” yet. But this should help understanding what is going on.

Comment: To check (3.54) explicitly, if you replace $m$ with $-m$ in the equation for $Y_{l,m}$ and substitute (3.51) for $P^{-m}_l$, you will get something that looks like $Y_{l,m}$, but with an extra factor of $(-1)^m$ and $e^{im\phi}$ replaced by $e^{-im\phi}$. Except for $(-1)^m$, this is just the complex conjugate of $Y_{l,m}$, as $e^{im\phi}$ is the only complex factor.

Answer (score 3):

The star * is probably what you think it is; the complex conjugate. Think about it like in quantum mechanics, $\langle \psi | \psi\rangle$ = $\int \psi^{*}\psi dx$. The spherical harmonics are complex.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I do not have quantum mechanics yet, but if they are complex, this makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to denote the complex conjugate.