# What do "ℜe" and "A*" mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, notation, complex-numbers

What do "$\mathfrak{Re}$" and "A*" mean in the following equation (taken from James Binney and David Skinner's [QM lecture notes](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JamesBinney/qb.pdf), equation 1.12),
\begin{align}
p(S\text{ or }T)&=\left|A\left(S\text{ or }T\right)\right|^2=\left|A(S)+A(T)\right|\\
&=\left|A(S)\right|^2+A(S)A^*(T)+A^*(S)A(T)+\left|A(T)\right|^2\\
&=p(S)+p(T)+2\mathfrak{Re}\left(A(S)A^*(T)\right).
\end{align}

EDIT: Why does the equation have

\begin{align}
\left(A(S)A^*(T)\right)
\end{align}

but not

\begin{align}
\left(A^*(S)A(T)\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19259/2451

Answer (score 9):

- $\mathfrak{R}e$: [real part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Definition).
- $A^*$: [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate) of probability amplitude $A$.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your edit:

The real part of $(A^*(S)A(T))$ is equal to the real part of $(A(S)A^*(T))$, since they are just complex conjugates of each other. So he could have written either one.

Concrete example: let $(A^*(S)A(T))=a+ib$ for some $a,b$. Then $(A(S)A^*(T))=a-ib$, since it's just the complex conjugate. Then $(A^*(S)A(T))+(A(S)A^*(T))=2a$. We can write $2a$ as either $2\mathfrak{Re}(a+ib)$ or $2\mathfrak{Re}(a-ib)$.